# trace down sigusr1, debug mex with gdb

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, gdb, signals, mex

Is there a way to trace down who sends the sigusr1?

It is for mex file created for Ubuntu, which hangs for certain condition. So I did:

```
1, mex -g *.c   (create .mex file)

2 matlab -Dgdb 
3 handle SIGUSR1 stop print
4 run -nojvm  (run matlab without gui)
5 dbmex on
6 run my executable
```

then it prints out: 
   MEX FILE: /home/X/Desktop/Test/test.mexa 64 entry point located at address 0xd11ea144
   Add breakpoints at the debugger prompt and issue a "continue" to resume execution of MATLAB

If I do "continue", my executable runs, then it hangs there again(I think the same as before).

I tried "bt" and "where", but still no clue where I get the SIGUSR1 and why it hangs.

For "where", I get:

```
#0 0x00007ffff5962ca4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0

#1 0x00007ffff69d7015 in mcr_run_main(boost::function0<int> const&, bool, bool)() from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so
#2 0x0000000000405291 in ?? ()
#3 0x00007ffff55b0ea5 in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

#4 0x0000000000405489 in ?? ()
#5 0x00007fffffffded8 in ?? ()
#6 0x000000000000001c in ?? ()
#7 0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()
#8 0x00007fffffffe208 in ?? ()
#9 0x00007fffffffe234 in ?? ()
#10 0x000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Can anyone help here point out the correct way to trace down the signal SIGUSR1 (which I think cause my exe to hang)? Thanks a lot!!

Updates:
set break points as suggested in the source files before and around suspicious code. then continue to track down bugs.

LJ

Comment: That's most likely happening due to a segmentation fault.  We can't figure out what's happening unless we see your MEX function.

Comment: Are you turning [dbmex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbmex.html) (`dbmex on`) on prior to running your mex file?

Comment: Thank you very much for all the responses. Yes, it probably means segmentation. but I don't know how to track it down.

Comment: Yes, Suever, I did it but forgot to type in here. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the `dbmex on` be after `run -nojvm`? i.e. it get's executed in matlab not gdb

Comment: yes, dbmex on after run -nojvm. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When stopped at a signal, you can `print $_siginfo`, and then examine the fields of this object to find the PID of the process that sent the signal.